# Cannot manually delete favorites in Safari in iOS 10.3.2

Tags: ipad, safari, ios, bookmarks

I've got an iPad 4 that I use irregularly, so I was a bit slow to update it to iOS 10.3.2. Since doing so, I've found that Safari takes a few tries to start up normally, and, when I try to delete a site from Favorites after accidentally adding it twice, it freezes up for a moment, and may or may not close, but does not delete the bookmark.

Two attempts so far have successfully deleted *a* bookmark, but in both cases it was the most recent, and not the one targeted. Hard resetting doesn't seem to help.

Frankly, I'm a n00b when it comes to Apple devices, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be very difficult to troubleshoot this based on the info you've provided.

Honestly, the iPad 4 is considered 'old' ([introduced in 2012](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-a1458-4th-gen-late-2012-wi-fi-only-specs.html)).  It does support the iOS version you're using but, like a 102 year-old man, it will struggle with some seemingly basic tasks like putting his pants on and using a spoon, simply because it's old.

If a reset didn't help, your only option might be to buy a new(er) device.